# jQuery to change color of second word in title/heading

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am currently using this JavaScript to change the color of the second word in each of my widget titles. But with this code, as it loops through each widget, it ends up printing all of the titles, from all of the widgets on the page, in each widget title. So for example, I have two widgets with titles "Recent Work" and "Recent Press". Work and Press are supposed to be orange. With this code, it outputs "Recent WorkRecent Press", where Work and Recent are both orange. This is printed the same in both widget titles. How can I edit this so it makes just the second, or last since each title will only be two words long, word orange?

```
var split = $("h4.widgettitle").text().split(" ");

if(split.length > 0) {
$("h4.widgettitle").html('').append("<span class='firstWord'>" + split[0] + "<span> ");

if(split.length > 1) {
    $("h4.widgettitle").append("<span class='secondWord'>" + split[1] + "<span> ");
    for(var i=2;i<split.length;i++) {
        $("h4.widgettitle").append(split[i] + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can help performance and clean up the code by doing this just once:  var $h4 = $("h4.widgettitle");  Then, access the variable instead of researching each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickest way:

```
$('h4.widgettitle').each(function(){

    var text = $(this).text().split(' ');
    if(text.length < 2)
        return;

    text[1] = '<span class="secondWord">'+text[1]+'</span>';

    $(this).html( text.join(' ') );

});
```

[See it running](http://jsfiddle.net/tmz9t/)

Answer (score 0):

something along these lines should work for you. It will color the second word red in all of your h4.widgettitle elements, regardless of how many words are in the title.

```
$("h4.widgettitle").each(function(){
    var title_list = $(this).text().split(" ");
    var new_title = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < title_list.length; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            new_title += "<span class='secondWord'>" + title_list[i] + "</span> ";
        } else {
            new_title += "<span class='notSecondWord'>" + title_list[i] + "</span> ";
        }
    }
    $(this).html(new_title);
})​​
```

Check it out in a [fiddle yo](http://jsfiddle.net/b3zu2/)